# Group by on a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, group-by

I'm afraid that it is simply not possible what I'm trying to do, but I hope you can help me to find a nice way to solve this problem.

I've got the following PHP-array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [article] => 10.499-1 [operation] => KN_KABEL [date] => 31-05-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [article] => 10.499-1 [operation] => LAS_LABEL [date] => 31-05-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [article] => 10.499-1 [operation] => ASS_HARNES [date] => 04-06-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [article] => 10.499-1 [operation] => CONTROLE [date] => 07-06-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [article] => 24.030 [operation] => LAS_LABEL [date] => 04-06-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [article] => 24.030 [operation] => ZAGEN-RAIL [date] => 04-06-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [article] => 24.030 [operation] => KN_KABEL [date] => 04-06-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [article] => 24.030 [operation] => ASS_RAIL [date] => 05-06-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [article] => 791 070-6/GS/P [operation] => GS_UNIT [date] => 04-06-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [article] => 791 070-6/GS/P [operation] => PR_UNIT [date] => 04-06-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [10] => Array ( [article] => 791 070-6/GS/P [operation] => LAS_LABEL [date] => 04-06-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [11] => Array ( [article] => ESS-0834E/LE-CD200 [operation] => MAGAZIJN [date] => 10-06-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [12] => Array ( [article] => ESS-0834E/LE-CD200 [operation] => PR_UNIT [date] => 11-06-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [13] => Array ( [article] => ESS-0834E/LE-CD200 [operation] => LAB_PLAKKE [date] => 11-06-2013 [hours] => 0 [quantity] => 1 )
)
```

What I'm trying to do is to count for each date (key "datum") the sum of hours (in this example they are all 0 but I still want to do this because this will change in the future). What would be very practicle is to do a query like sql like `SELECT SUM(hours) GROUP BY date` but this is no SQL unfortunately.

Is there a way to group (and order) my array by a specific key (in this case "date") or, if not, is there an other way to get the result what I want?

**EDIT**

I recently added a key "department" which should be grouped by to. Thereby I do not only want to count the sum of "hours", but "quantity" too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create simply foreach for this.

```
$arr = array();

$sums = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
     if(!isset($sums[$v['date']][$v['department']]['hours'])) $sums[$v['date']][$v['department']]['hours'] = 0;
     if(!isset($sums[$v['date']][$v['department']]['quantity'])) $sums[$v['date']][$v['department']]['quantity'] = 0;
     $sums[$v['date']][$v['department']]['hours'] += $v['hours'];
     $sums[$v['date']][$v['department']]['quantity'] += $v['quantity'];
}
print_r($sums);
```

it will create array `$sum` where keys are your dates. If value doesn't exists it will add the value of hours to 0, else if it exists it will add to existing value.

**edit**

Fitted to OP needs.

Comment: that's really useable for me, thanks! 2 questions? I've added a key "department" in my array. Is it also possible to "group by" 2 colums. And second: I want to count the key "quantity" too. Is it possible to do this in the same code? Sorry for not noticing this in my question at all. I will edit my question with the additional requirements

Comment: of course it is possible `$sums[$v['date']][$v['department']]` small change and it works :) quantity can be counted on the same way ;) $sums[$v['date']][$v['department']] the value of array can be also array where you can put hours and quantity and sum it.

Comment: you removed your "in_array()" part from your code, was that your intention or did you forgot it? Because now I'm getting a lot of undifined index errors